# opendir() in C Programming

Tags: c, directory, opendir, dirent.h

I'm a beginner and I am making a code about getting the directory of a file, but I have something that I don't understand.

What's the meaning of "./" in `DS = opendir ("./");`

I have searched a lot of sites about C programming, but nothing gave me a good explanation. I have to present my code soon, forcing me to explain every single line of my code. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/107_6.htm) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./` is a relative path which is relative to the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your process.

> In computing, the working directory of a process is a directory of a hierarchical file system, if any, dynamically associated with each process. When the process refers to a file using a simple file name or relative path (as opposed to a file designated by a full path from a root directory), the reference is interpreted relative to the current working directory of the process.

So suppose the working directory of your process is `/foo`, when you open `./` with `opendir`, you are actually opening `/foo/./` which is equal to `/foo`.

Comment: Could you explain it in a more simple way? I am still a beginner in programming. I do know that `DS = opendir ("./");` will open all the files included in the folder where my code is. What I don't understand how will I explain to beginner programmers like me and make them understand as well.

Comment: This will not open all the files. It will open the directory. Like you can read data from an open file, you can read from an open directory. This yields a list of files inside that directory.

Comment: `opendir` only opens that directory, not files inside it as answered in previous comment. Also if you want to `get the directory of a file`, you must know where the file is first, rather absolute path or relative path.

Comment: Wow thanks! But how about something like `DS = opendir (".");`? What will it do?

Comment: `opendir(".")` is same to `opendir("./")`, check man page of [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) to see what it does.