# stat() function only works in the current directory C language

Tags: c, directory, stat

i'm using C on windows to read the contents of a directory and info about each entry, however the stat() function only works if i opened the current directory "."

`directory = opendir(".")`

whenever i try something like this "C:\Users\User\Desktop\programming" it does not work and outputs -1

`directory = opendir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\programming")`

can you pleas guide me here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
void perror(const char *str);// for error detail 

int main()
{
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat info;
    int entries = 0 ;

    // entering the directory
    directory = opendir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\programming");//also C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\programming\\ didn't work
    if ( directory == NULL )
        {
            puts("the directory couldn't be accessed or does not exist");
          return(2);
        }


    printf("No   type         name              size           TimeStamp \n\n");
    while((file=readdir(directory))!= NULL)
    {

        entries++;

              //  problem : the stat is not working properly 
        stat(file->d_name,&info);
        if ((stat(file->d_name,&info)) == -1){
            printf("can't find %s\n", file->d_name);
            perror("ERROR");
           }
        // show the number of the entry
        printf("%2d  ",entries);

        // determine if file or directory
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            printf("Dir ");
        else

            printf("File");

        // display the name of the file
        printf("%20s",file->d_name);

        // display the size of the file
        printf("%10d",info.st_size);

        // show the last modified time
        if(!(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)))
            printf("%30s\n",ctime(&info.st_mtime));
        else puts("\n");

    }




    return(0);
}
```

the output pic link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/tORZU.png

Comment: Use `perror` to get additional error output

Comment: i used it and it shows " No such file or directory "

Comment: BTW Why are you calling `stat(file->d_name,&info);` twice?

Comment: by mistake, though it doesn't affect the code

Comment: regarding the statement: `void perror(const char *str);`  the prototype is already exposed via: `#include <stdio.h>`  so no need to write that prototype.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  this statement: `printf("%30s\n",ctime(&info.st_mtime));` results in the compiler outputting: `untitled1.c:53:24: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]` because the code is missing the statement: `#include <time.h>` so the compiler assumes the return type from `ctime()` is `int` rather than the actual: `char *`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%10d",info.st_size);` the field `st_size` is a `long int`, not an `int`.  the result is a compiler warning.  Suggest: `printf("%10ld",info.st_size);`  notice the output format specifier is `ld` not `d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. includes all the needed header files
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for and handles errors
4. properly sets up the path for the `stat()` function
5. note: the code is being run from the `/home/richard/documents/forum` directory.  This shows that the proposed code properly handles cross directory references.
6. hidden files are kept hidden by ignoring entries that start with '.'

and now, the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>



int main( void )
{
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat info;
    int entries = 0 ;

    // entering the directory
    directory = opendir("//home//richard" );
    if ( directory == NULL )
    {
        perror("the directory couldn't be accessed or does not exist");
        return(2);
    }


    printf("No   type         name              size           TimeStamp \n\n");
    while((file = readdir(directory)))
    {
        if( file->d_name[0] == '.' )
        { // then hidden file, so leave hidden
            continue;
        }

        entries++;

        char buffer[1024];
        strcpy( buffer, "//home//richard//" );
        strcat( buffer, file->d_name );
        if (stat( buffer, &info ) == -1)
        {
            perror( buffer );
            continue;
        }
        // show the number of the entry
        printf("%2d  ",entries);

        // determine if file or directory
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            printf("Dir ");
        else
            printf("File");

        // display the name of the file
        printf("%20s",file->d_name);

        // display the size of the file
        printf("%10ld",info.st_size);

        // show the last modified time
        if(!(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)))
            printf("%30s\n",ctime(&info.st_mtime));
        else puts("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Part of the output from a typical run of the code is:

```
No   type         name              size           TimeStamp 

 1  Dir                Music      4096

 2  Dir             projects      4096

 3  Dir         scull-master      4096

 4  Dir         slickeditpro      4096

 5  Dir                 snap      4096

 6  File   clamscanParms.txt       171     Sat May 20 10:06:43 2017

 7  Dir              OpenMPI      4096

 8  Dir        clamav.0.99.2      4096

 9  Dir               Public      4096

10  Dir            Documents      4096

11  Dir              Desktop      4096

12  Dir            Downloads     20480

13  Dir             Pictures      4096

14  Dir            Templates      4096

15  Dir               Videos      4096

16  File        clamscan.log     42952     Tue Feb 18 13:24:58 2020
```

As you can see, there are still some alignment between column headers and column data discrepancies that need correction.  I'm sure you can handle that detail.

Comment: Good proposal, Richard. +1

Comment: @user3629249 thank you very much, i see how it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( (stat(file->d_name, &info) ) == -1) { ...
```

`file->d_name` contains only a string with the name of the file, but not its path. `stat()` needs to have the exact path to the file as first argument.

---

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 

int main (void)
{
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat info;
    int entries = 0 ;
    char* path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\programming";

    // entering the directory
    directory = opendir(path);

    if ( directory == NULL )
    {
        puts("the directory couldn't be accessed or does not exist");
        return(2);
    }


    printf("No   type         name              size           TimeStamp \n\n");

    while((file=readdir(directory))!= NULL)
    {

        entries++;

              //  problem : the stat is not working properly 

        if (stat(path, &info) == -1){
            printf("can't find %s\n", file->d_name);
            perror("ERROR");
           }
        // show the number of the entry
        printf("%2d  ",entries);

        // determine if file or directory
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            printf("Dir ");
        else

            printf("File");

        // display the name of the file
        printf("%20s",file->d_name);

        // display the size of the file
        printf("%10d",info.st_size);

        // show the last modified time
        if(!(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)))
            printf("%30s\n",ctime(&info.st_mtime));
        else puts("\n");

    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: i need to use "\\" since my editor evaluates "\" as an escape sequence

Comment: @AX360 What happens exactly if you do so? Do you get a warning or is it an error which doesn´t let the code compile?

Comment: it just outputs all entries as directories .. i'm going to add a pic in a sec of the output

Comment: @AX360 What is the name of the user profile? You need to replace `User` with the `user name`.

Comment: my profile name is User ^_^' , you can see it in the cmd's window title in the pic

Comment: @AX360 Just to be sure... ^^

Comment: great i tried the second tip and there is no ERROR but still it reads all entries as directories even though some are .txt files

Comment: 1. Is totally wrong. 2. is correct. The standard says that the backslash **SHALL** be presented as \\ in strings and character literals, there are no *buts*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Normally yes, *but* for the path strings in for `opendir()` it seems to be different. All examples I found are using a single `\\` inside of the the path string. http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fo%2Fopendir.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242665/c-opendir-always-null

Comment: @AnttiHaapala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728052/opendir-in-c-programming

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Same goes for `stat()`. It seems that actually both ways are possible even if the single / method isn´t standard-compliant. I´ll delete the first point, but it shall work nonetheless.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%30s\n",ctime(&info.st_mtime));`  This does not compile because the code is missing the statement: `#include <time.h>` so the returned type from `ctime()` is assumed to be `int` rather than `char *`

Comment: @user3629249 I didn´t run the code myself (my bad, I know) before. I just was looking for a mismatch at the file operation function calls itself.